# record and automate http request

Tags: http, networking, httprequest

I have a general router and I would like to record the config steps and then execute them again .. steps will be over http

would you please provide me with a reliabe tool or an open source application or browser addon that can help with this task

Answer (score 0):

Try Selenium, its an tool for automation testing

http://seleniumhq.org/